# Why is Ubuntu 12.10 freezing and windows becoming greyed out?

Tags: 12.10, freeze

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 since it was released last April. (I upgraded to 12.10 in October.)

Suddenly it began running very *very* poorly, acting as if I was using too much RAM or saturating my CPU. The system monitor and `top` did not seem to confirm this; I was only using about 30% of my RAM and barely any CPU.

Windows began greying out randomly and frequently and the system completely froze a few times. I figured this was some junk I'd been tinkering with over the year, so I backed up my data and formatted, then re-installed. After booting back up, I saw that the problems persisted.

System info:

- White box pc
- Intel Core2 Duo e8400
- 4GB DDR2 800Mhz
- Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS
- Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Let me know if you need any further information. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the log from commands like dmesg or what /var/log/syslog or kern.log say?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Zram in terminal? Also have you tried installing Preload from the Ubuntu Software centre.  I used Preload and that sped up my pc quite well.  Well that's all the suggestions I have.  Also type in google search "4 things to speed up Ubuntu" Try looking at the video from Nixie Pixel, she does vlogs every week and had a video on how to speed up Ubuntu.  Hope this helps good luck! :)

One last thing you might have a bad sector or something on your hard drive, how old is the computer?

Comment: (Posted on behalf of new user [@cootje](http://askubuntu.com/users/141076/cootje)) - `zram` is intended for use on computers that have low RAM. (512 KB or less), [according to this site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed#TOC-For-512-MB-RAM-or-less:-enable-zRam). So with 4 GB, it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get install preload -y
```

Thanks Mike.